# Spark and Cassandra Java application: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax

I got an amazingly siplme java application which I almost copied from this one example: http://markmail.org/download.xqy?id=zua6upabiylzeetp&number=2

All I wanted to do is to read the table data and display in the Eclipse console.

My pom.xml:

```
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>chat_connaction_test</groupId>
  <artifactId>ChatSparkConnectionTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <dependencies> 
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--
    <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId> 
    <version>1.5.2</version> 
    </dependency>
    -->
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And my java code:

```
    package com.chatSparkConnactionTest;

import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraRow;

public class JavaDemo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().
            setAppName("chat").
            setMaster("local").
            set("spark.executor.memory","1g").
            set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        JavaRDD<String> cassandraRowsRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable(
            "chat", "dictionary")

            .map(new Function<CassandraRow, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(CassandraRow cassandraRow) throws Exception {
                    String tempResult = cassandraRow.toString();
                    System.out.println(tempResult);
                    return tempResult;
                    }
                }
            );
        System.out.println("Data as CassandraRows: \n" + 
        cassandraRowsRDD.collect().size()); // THIS IS A LINE WITH ERROR
    } 
}
```

And here is my error:

> 16/10/05 20:49:18 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra
>   cluster: Test Cluster Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getPrivateMethod(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1700(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)    at
>   scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.writeObject(List.scala:379)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2037)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1896)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1911)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:893)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:892)   at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:360)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
>     at com.chatSparkConnactionTest.JavaDemo.main(JavaDemo.java:37) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 58 more

I made my pom.xml updated but that didn't resolve the error. Could anybody help me to resolve this problem?

Thank you!

Update 1:
here is my build path screenshot:
[Link to my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQhp9.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset" error because "spark-sql" dependency is missing from your pom.xml file.

If you want to read Cassandra table with Spark 2.0.0 then you need below minimum dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
</dependency>
```

Spark 2.0.0 provides SparkSession and Dataset API. Below is the sample program for reading Cassandra table and printing the records.

```
 public class SparkCassandraDatasetApplication {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 SparkSession spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("SparkCassandraDatasetApplication")
          .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/file:C:/temp")
          .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
          .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
          .master("local[2]")
          .getOrCreate();

 //Read data
 Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
            {
                put("keyspace", "mykeyspace");
                put("table", "mytable");
            }
        }).load();

   //Print data
   dataset.show();       
   spark.stop();
   }        
}
```

If you still want to use RDD then use below sample program.

```
public class SparkCassandraRDDApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("SparkCassandraRDDApplication")
            .setMaster("local[2]")
            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042");

    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    //Read
    JavaRDD<UserData> resultsRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("mykeyspace", "mytable",CassandraJavaUtil.mapRowTo(UserData.class));

    //Print
    resultsRDD.foreach(data -> {
        System.out.println(data.id);
        System.out.println(data.username);
    });

    sc.stop();
  }
}
```

Javabean (UserData) used in above program is like below.

```
public class UserData implements Serializable{  
  String id;
  String username;     
  public String getId() {
      return id;
  }
  public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
  }
  public String getUsername() {
     return username;
  }
  public void setUsername(String username) {
     this.username = username;
   }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! All works for today (I added dependencies as you described)

Comment: Just a small extra question - which one way is preferable if I need json as an output - **SparkSession and Dataset API** or **RDD**?

Comment: I researched, Dataset API is definitely preferable in my case

Comment: could you please add complete POM and how you are submitting it to spark?

Comment: @hasson please post a separate question with what are you doing and issues you are getting and I will try to help you. Thanks

Comment: @abaghel thanks, here is my question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/40221743/3771299

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to ensure that following resources is present in your class path:

```
cassandra-driver-core-2.1.0.jar
metrics-core-3.0.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
netty-3.9.0-Final.jar
guava-16.0.1.jar
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Hello Abu, thank you for the response. I added these files to my build path (I will add a link with the screenshot in the end of my question) but I still got the same error: Test Cluster
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset. What else I could try?

Comment: Can you add this please and let me know:                              <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: Yep, but still same thing: Test Cluster
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset

Comment: How do you submit spark job?

Comment: All fixed with abaghel comment. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10 -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
<version>1.6.0-M1</version>
</dependency>
```

You are mixing versions on the classpath. The java module is included within the core module in Spark Cassandra Connector 2.0.0. So this just pulls in spark 1.6 references.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Still got an error. This is how my dependencies for right now (I updated main question)

Comment: All fixed with abaghel comment. Thanks again