# Spark and Cassandra Java Application Exception Provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem not found

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I want to load cassandra table to a datafram in spark, I have followed the sample programes below (found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39890996/3771299)), but I am getting an execption mentioned below, 
I have tried to load the table to RDD first then convert it to Datafrme, loading the RDD is successful, but when I try to convert it to a dataframe I am getting the same execption faced in the first methdology, any suggestions ? I am using Spark 2.0.0, Cassandra 3.7, and Java 8.

```
 public class SparkCassandraDatasetApplication {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 SparkSession spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("SparkCassandraDatasetApplication")
          .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/file:C:/temp")
          .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
          .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
          .master("local[2]")
          .getOrCreate();

 //Read data to dataframe
 // this is throwing an exception
 Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
            {
                put("keyspace", "mykeyspace");
                put("table", "mytable");
            }
        }).load();

   //Print data
   dataset.show();       
   spark.stop();
   }        
}
```

When submitted I am getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem not found
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2623)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2634)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2651)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.makeQualifiedPath(SessionCatalog.scala:115)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.createDatabase(SessionCatalog.scala:145)
```

Using the RDD method to read from cassandra is successful ( i have tested it with count() call), but converting the RDD to DF is throwing the same exception faced in the first method.

```
public class SparkCassandraRDDApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
             SparkSession spark = SparkSession
              .builder()
              .appName("App")
              .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/file:/opt/spark/temp")
              .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
              .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
              .master("local[2]")
              .getOrCreate();

    SparkContext sc = spark.sparkContext();

    //Read
    JavaRDD<UserData> resultsRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("mykeyspace", "mytable",CassandraJavaUtil.mapRowTo(UserData.class));

    //This is again throwing an exception
    Dataset<Row> usersDF = spark.createDataFrame(resultsRDD, UserData.class);

    //Print
    resultsRDD.foreach(data -> {
        System.out.println(data.id);
        System.out.println(data.username);
    });

    sc.stop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if "hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar" is available in classpath. You can test your application by creating a jar including all the dependencies. Use below pom.xml in which maven-shade-plugin is used to include all the dependencies to create uber jar.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.abaghel.examples.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-cassandra</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.abaghel.examples.spark.cassandra.SparkCassandraDatasetApplication</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

You can run the jar like below

```
spark-submit --class com.abaghel.examples.spark.cassandra.SparkCassandraDatasetApplication spark-cassandra-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I was using some kind of minimizer with shading and some strange settings to avoid guava v19 and v16 clashing together, but it was not working with DF, your POM solved my problem, many thanks.