# Spark read() works but sql() throws Database not found

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 2.1 to read data from Cassandra in Java.
I tried the code posted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39890996/1151472 (with SparkSession) and it worked. However when I replaced spark.read() method with spark.sql() one, the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: `wiki`.`treated_article`; line 1 pos 14;
'Project [*]
+- 'UnresolvedRelation `wiki`.`treated_article`

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
```

I'm using same spark configuration for both read and sql methods

read() code:
Dataset dataset =

```
spark.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                .options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                    {
                        put("keyspace", "wiki");
                        put("table", "treated_article");
                    }
                }).load();
```

sql() code:

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM WIKI.TREATED_ARTICLE");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark Sql uses a `Catalogue` to look up database and table references. When you write in a table identifier that isn't in the catalogue it will throw errors like the one you posted. The `read` command doesn't require a catalogue since you are required to specify all of the relevant information in the invocation.

You can add entries to the catalogue either by

#### Registering DataSets as Views

First create your DataSet

```
spark.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                .options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                    {
                        put("keyspace", "wiki");
                        put("table", "treated_article");
                    }
                }).load();
```

Then use one of the catalogue registry functions

```
void    createGlobalTempView(String viewName)
Creates a global temporary view using the given name.
void    createOrReplaceTempView(String viewName)
Creates a local temporary view using the given name.
void    createTempView(String viewName)
Creates a local temporary view using the given name
```

#### OR Using a SQL Create Statement

```
   CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW words
     USING org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra
     OPTIONS (
       table "words",
       keyspace "test",
       cluster "Test Cluster",
       pushdown "true"
     )
```

Once added to the catalogue by either of these methods you can reference the table in all `sql` calls issued by that context.

---

Example

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW words
  USING org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra
  OPTIONS (
    table "words",
    keyspace "test"
  );

SELECT * FROM words;
// Hello    1
// World    2
```

---

The Datastax (My employer) Enterprise software automatically registers all Cassandra tables by placing entries in the Hive Metastore used by Spark as a Catalogue. This makes all tables accessible without manual registration.

This method allows for select statements to be used without an accompanying `CREATE VIEW`

Comment: Thanks a lot Russ .. you just made my day

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a way to make that work off the top of my head. The problem lies in that Spark doesn't know the format to try, and the location that this would be specified is taken by the keyspace. The closest documentation for something like this that I can find is [here in the DataFrames section](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#example-creating-a-source-using-spark-sql) of the Cassandra connector documentation. You can try to specify a `using` statement, but I don't think that will work inside of a select. So, your best bet beyond that is to create a PR to handle this case, or stick with the read DSL.